# Gracenote API request not returning link to iTunes / Amazon

Tags: gracenote

As part of the reponse to my webAPI queries, I currently receive an external link to the DEEZER service, but I'm looking to retrieve links to iTunes, Amazon.

Is there any additional setup needed to get these links to Amazon and iTunes returned? There appears to be no documentation of the process, and the rep at Gracenote has confirmed this is a feature (amazon and itunes links).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question - Gracenote developer accounts don't get access to iTunes and other vendors unless you have a paid account. You can arrange a sample account to get time restricted access to these IDs, but ultimately you must have a paid account to develop against.